# NodeJS map rendering libraries other than Mapnik

Tags: rasterization, linux, node-js

I'm looking for a library to call from Node that can render a fairly simple map (a single polygon, with text labels along edges) from GeoJSON to a PNG. I have a working solution using Mapnik, but that is causing problems getting it installed on MacOS. It also has to work on Amazon Linux (for Lambda).

Are there any other candidate libraries?